# Unable to start existing react native project. Facing gradle issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native, gradle

I am trying to run a react-native project in my macOS.
I have done npm install uninstall , clean gradle but still facing the same issue.

When i run npm start i am facing the below issue.

```
info Opening the app on Android...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
   > Failed to create parent directory '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle' when creating directory '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-gradle-plugin'.
> Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
   > Failed to create parent directory '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle' when creating directory '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup'

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I don't what went wrong or which step i miss when setting up environment for react-native.

---

Also running ios app from npm start return similar result.

```
The workspace named "ealpha" does not contain a scheme named "ealpha". The "-list" option can be used to find the names of the schemes in the workspace.
```

EDITED-----

Currently i am getting the below error.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/android/settings.gradle' (/Users/ealpha4tech/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/scripts/bx94o9il2py3wpbok5l2mnec2).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65
```

Comment: Your build is failing to create a directory. Does it have write access to the destination location? If all else fails try running the build as admin.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried now another error is coming.
Build file '/Users/ealpha4tech/Downloads/ealpha4-mobile-main 2/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle' line: 10

Plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react'] was not found in any of the following sources:

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

1. Go with this link : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34410
2. Go with this link : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/38034

**Solution 2**

1. Clean your Gradle cache: This can sometimes resolve Gradle issues. To do this, run the command : ./gradlew clean or gradle clean
2. Consider rebuilding your project. By doing this, Gradle will be compelled
   to rebuild your project from fresh and download any missing dependencies.
   Use the following command to accomplish this : gradle build or ./gradle
   build

**Solution 3**

1. You can remove current installed JDK with (MacOS):

   sudo rm -rf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk.jdk
   Next, download it from the official Oracle website and launch the
   application.